# How to regex replace all characters of specific type in lines that have a specific word

Tags: regex, notepad++

There is a multiline text, in which there are specific lines that i'm interested in indicated by specific words. For example i am interested in the lines that have ".jpg" in them.

```
I'm trying to use a lookahead:
(?=\.jpg)
```

In these lines i would like to delete specific characters, for example all matches of "_"

```
Sample input:

https://somewebpage/stuff1_stuff2_stuff3.jpg

Desired output:

https://somewebpage/stuff1stuff2stuff3.jpg
```

I'm trying to write this regex for latest notepad++

My problem is that i can't seem to properly combine the positive lookahead with my regex recursively

```
([^_]*)(_?)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a fragment of the file and expected output.

Comment: There are multiple urls in the file, I have posted samples in my question.

Comment: And these URLs are all on separate lines? No other text beside them?

Comment: It's a json file, so the only thing that comes before the url is the tag name, for example:

    "TableURL": "https://somewebpage/stuff1_stuff2_stuff3.jpg",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[_-](?=.*\.jpg)` worked for me. replace with empty string to remove the characters or just do a find. you can expand your character list of course, but I think this covers you.

Comment: Actually, it should look like `[_-](?=.*\.jpg)`. Placing lookahead at the starting position in the pattern will cause redundant backtracking overhead.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I've updated my response accordingly.